# .NET app returning different OS version to PowerShell on Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, windows, powershell, windows-10

I'm trying to determine the OS version in a .NET application which already uses System.Environment.OSVersion to successfully determine the version for all versions of Windows up to Windows 8.1.

However, when calling `System.Environment.OSVersion` in a .NET app on Windows 10, the version returned is `Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0` (which is exactly the same output as on Windows 8.1). However, when calling `[System.Environment]::OSVersion` via PowerShell the output gives me `Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.10240.0`.

I was under the impression that PowerShell uses .NET under the hood and expected both calls to return exactly the same output. Why is there a discrepancy in the output and more importantly, how can I detect if my app is running on Windows 10?

Comment: Your claim is wrong, as the 8.1 output you noticed is in fact for Windows 8 compatibility. Check the app.config of PowerShell console to study the hack you need to include in your own.

Comment: @LexLi Actually, my claim is correct as it is the observed behaviour. Also, the observed behaviour goes against the principle of least astonishment which affirms my claim further. Now where, pray tell, is this mythical config you allude to?

Comment: check the answer and it says all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think [this is the cause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx):

> With the release of Windows 8.1, the behavior of the `GetVersion` API has changed in the value it will return for the operating system version. The value returned by the GetVersion function now depends on how the application is manifested.
>
> *Applications not manifested for Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 will return the Windows 8 OS version value (6.2).*

Comment: For reference, the `System.Environment.OSVersion` property implementation: [System.Environment.OSVersion](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/environment.cs,67900ccbbcff63a2).

Comment: Thanks, just needed to add the Windows 10 GUID as a supported OS in the manifest file.